# access line information, line id number and onChanged event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devexpress, devextreme

How can I get the line information and id number I want to edit.
Also how can I access the onChanged event?
Can you help me ?

1. I want to get the line information I want to edit.
2. I want to get the id number of the line I want to edit.
3. How can I access onChanged events? So how can I understand when textfield changes?

`

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
  import { EditingState,SearchState,IntegratedFiltering, GroupingState,  IntegratedGrouping,} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
  import {  ColumnChooser,  Grid,  Table,  TableColumnResizing,  TableColumnVisibility,  TableEditColumn,  TableEditRow,  TableFixedColumns,  TableHeaderRow,  Toolbar,  SearchPanel,  TableGroupRow,  GroupingPanel,  DragDropProvider,} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';


  class UserInformation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoaded: true,
       columns: [
         {name: 'name', title: 'Name'},
         {name: 'city', title: 'city'}
       ],
       rows : [
         { sex: "Female", name: "Sandra", city: "Las Vegas", car: "Audi A4" },
         { sex: "Male", name: "Paul", city: "Paris", car: "Nissan Altima" },
         { sex: "Male", name: "Mark", city: "Paris", car: "Honda Accord" },
         { sex: "Male", name: "Paul", city: "Paris", car: "Nissan Altima" },
         { sex: "Female", name: "Linda", city: "Austin", car: "Toyota Corolla" }
       ]
     };
     this.commitChanges = this.commitChanges.bind(this);
    //this.getRowId = this.getRowId.bind(this);
    }
   }




   commitChanges({ added, changed, deleted }) {
     let { rows } = this.state;
     let changedRows;

     if (added) {
       console.log("added")
      }
     if (changed) {
       changedRows = rows.map(row => (changed[row.id] ? { ...row, ...changed[row.id] } : row));
       console.log("changed");
       console.log(rows.map(row => (changed[row.id])))
      }
     if (deleted) {
       console.log("deleted")
     }
    };
    //getRowId(row) {
    //  console.log(this.state.rows.indexOf(row));
    //  return this.state.rows.indexOf(row);
    //}


   render() {
     const { isLoaded, drList, rows, columns } = this.state;
     if (!isLoaded) {
       return <div>Loading...</div>;
     } else {
       return (
         <div className={"animated fadeIn "}>
        <Row>
           <Paper>
              <Grid
               rows={rows}
               columns={columns}
               getRowId={this.getRowId}
             >
            <EditingState
             onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
            />
            <Table
              /*columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}*/
            />
            <TableHeaderRow />
            <TableEditRow />
            <TableEditColumn
             showAddCommand
             showEditCommand
             showDeleteCommand
           />
           </Grid>
         </Paper>
         </Row>
       </div>
     );
     }
    }
   }
   export default UserInformation;
```

Comment: You can pass the index from the `rows` array to the functions and edit them by that index

Comment: can you do with sample? I searched, I could not find. Can you give an example?

Comment: Create a working sandbox with what you have and I'll try to help you from there